# Django / Django Rest Framework ModelViewSet: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a custom "list" under OptionViewSet but It's giving me an error.

```
class OptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OptionSerializer
    queryset = Option.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Option.objects.all()
        serializer = OptionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Error

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This works fine:

```
class OptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OptionSerializer
    queryset = Option.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
path('api/shipping/', include((shipping_routes.urls, 'shipping'), namespace='shipping')),
```

routes.py

```
routes.register(r'option', OptionViewSet, basename='option')
```

serializer

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ['id', 'extra', 'name']
```

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Simon\.virtualenvs\django_backend-ZmgaAA1F\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\Documents\GitHub\crud-react-django\django_backend\shipping\views.py", line 18, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/shipping/option/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback, and also your serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong Response import. Imported it from "requests" instead of "rest_framework.response".

Answer (score -1):

In the url.py, in the the specific path from urlpatters[] you need to call your `views.OptionViewSet.as_view()` as a middle parameter between the URL path and the name reference:

```
path('api/shipping/', include((shipping_routes.urls, 'shipping'), namespace='shipping')),
```

Django has very good documentation and you can read more about the Django-Rest-Framework's ViewSets here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

*edit*: From the exception stack trace we can see that url.py is refering to a problem with `/api/shipping/option/` which essentially is the routes.py's record with `basename='option'`

Seems like you might need to adjust routes.py from

`routes.register(r'option', OptionViewSet, basename='option')`

to

`routes.register(r'option', OptionViewSet.as_view(), basename='option')`

Can you please give it a go and let us know how it goes!

Comment: This doesn't work